# ververica platform | Flink Required context properties mismatch

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to submit a job to ververica platform deployed in Kubernates but I got the message below, I submit the same code to Flink standalone and its works normal!! I'm using Flink 1.10.1 and code with Scala 2.12.

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableSinkFactory' in
the classpath.

Reason: Required context properties mismatch.

The following properties are requested:

connector.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
connector.password=****** 
connector.table=***** 
connector.type=jdbc
connector.url=jdbc:mysql://********** 
connector.username=******** 
schema.0.data-type=VARCHAR(255) 
schema.0.name=********** 
schema.1.data-type=BIGINT 
schema.1.name=**** 
schema.2.data-type=VARCHAR(255)
schema.2.name=***** 
schema.3.data-type=DATE
schema.3.name=****** 
schema.4.data-type=BIGINT
schema.4.name=****** 
schema.5.data-type=VARCHAR(255)
schema.5.name=************ 
schema.6.data-type=DATE
schema.6.name=*********

The following factories have been considered:
org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvBatchTableSinkFactory
org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvAppendTableSinkFactory
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:335)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:205)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getPipeline(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.getPipelineFromProgram(PackagedProgramUtils.java:108)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:58)
        at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.ClassPathJobGraphRetriever.retrieveJobGraph(ClassPathJobGraphRetriever.java:104)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableSinkFactory' in
the classpath.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that Flink didn't find a TableFactory to generate the connector to write to the MySQL table.

You should bundle the JDBC Table/SQL connector with your program JAR.

Comment: I tried to generate the jar with command `sbt assembly` but still get the same error

Comment: You can unzip the generated JAR file to check if the required classes are included.

Comment: Yes I checked the JAR and the class exist.

Comment: Thank you Fabian it fixed my problem, and also I mentioned in my code I didnt use BlinkPlanner and that also generate an error in TableSource